# Javascript : Calling "pubilc Variable" from "private Method"

Tags: javascript, class

I need to call some private Variable when user click on a button which call a Function from one of my Class.

Here is my code :-

```
class01 = new MyClass('Tom Marvolo Riddle');

function MyClass(name){

    this.name = name;

    var draw = function(){
        var newHTML ='<input type="button" value="hello" />';
        $(".ctn").append(function(){
            return $(newHTML).click(hello);
        });
    }

    var hello = function(){
        alert ('hello, my name is '+this.name+'.')
    }

    draw();

}
```

Comment: You lost the context by introducing a new scope. Cache `this` eg: `var self=this` then use `self`.

Comment: Alternatively, try  `var hello = function(){ alert ('hello, my name is '+this.name+'.'); }.bind(this);` - bind keeps the context.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum post as answer?

Comment: I like @BenjaminGruenbaum 's answer most, it didn't need to declare any variable. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the `hello` function, when it is invoked, `this` refers to the button clicked, which will not have the `name` attribute which we stored. So, we capture the current object while assigning `name`, in another variable,  like this

```
function MyClass(name){

    var that = this;
    that.name = name;

    ...
    var hello = function(){
        console.log ('hello, my name is ' + that.name + '.');
    }
    draw();
}

var class01 = new MyClass('Tom Marvolo Riddle');
```